# WebpackError: #95313 Gatsby Building failed

Tags: reactjs, webpack, gatsby, react-three-fiber

I looked up many threads but i couldn´t find a related thread to this so I´m asking here.
I basically added a GLTF file (which i declared in Sushi.jsx) in my gatsby site using the @drei dependency.
On my local development server everything works fine: no errors with gatsby develop or gatsby build. But on my ubuntu droplet it always throws this WebpackError: #95313.
Im not sure if this is related to the 3D Model or it is just a converting error from @drei itself..

```
 ERROR #95313 

Building static HTML failed

See our docs page for more info on this error: https://gatsby.dev/debug-html


  12 | }
  13 |
> 14 | const createImageUrl = (blob, type) => URL.createObjectURL(new
Blob([fixBinary(atob(blob))], {
     | ^
  15 |   type
  16 | }));
  17 |


  WebpackError: ReferenceError: Blob is not defined
  
  - base64.js:14 
    node_modules/drei/helpers/base64.js:14:1
  
  - cloud.base64.js:4 
    node_modules/drei/assets/cloud.base64.js:4:32
  
  - Cloud.js:1 
    node_modules/drei/Cloud.js:1:1
  
  - index.js:1 
    node_modules/drei/index.js:1:1
  
  - Sushi.jsx:1 
    src/components/Sushi/Sushi.jsx:1:1
  
  - Hero.jsx:1 
    src/components/Hero/Hero.jsx:1:1
  
  - App.jsx:1 
    src/components/App.jsx:1:1
  
  - index.js:1 
    src/pages/index.js:1:1
    

My dependencies are down here: 

"dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.0",
    "drei": "^2.2.21",
    "gatsby": "^2.23.7",
    "gatsby-image": "^2.4.7",
    "gatsby-plugin-manifest": "^2.4.12",
    "gatsby-plugin-offline": "^3.2.11",
    "gatsby-plugin-react-helmet": "^3.3.4",
    "gatsby-plugin-sass": "^2.3.4",
    "gatsby-plugin-sharp": "^2.6.12",
    "gatsby-source-filesystem": "^2.3.12",
    "gatsby-transformer-sharp": "^2.3.16",
    "nanoid": "^3.1.10",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-github-btn": "^1.2.0",
    "react-helmet": "^6.1.0",
    "react-native-animated-emoji": "^0.1.4",
    "react-reveal": "^1.2.2",
    "react-scroll": "^1.7.16",
    "react-spring": "^8.0.27",
    "react-three-fiber": "^5.1.4",
    "react-tilt": "^0.1.4",
    "react-typewriter-effect": "^1.0.2",
    "three": "^0.122.0",
    "typewriter-effect": "^2.17.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "eslint": "^6.8.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^18.2.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^6.11.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.21.2",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.3.1",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.4",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.20.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.0.4",
    "husky": "^4.2.5",
    "lint-staged": "^10.2.11",
    "prettier": "^2.0.5"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby-starter-hello-world"
  },
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues"
  },
  "husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "pre-commit": "lint-staged"
    }
  },
  "lint-staged": {
    "*.+(js|jsx)": [
      "eslint --fix",
      "git add"
    ],
    "*.+(json|css|md)": [
      "prettier --write",
      "git add"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Which Node versions are running both?

Comment: Node.js v15.0.1. on the droplet
Node.js v12.19.0. on my local system

Answer (score 1):

According to:

> Node.js v15.0.1. on the droplet Node.js v12.19.0. on my local system

This is causing mismatching dependency versions. What is running and working under `v12.19.0` apparently is not in the `v15.0.1`.

Use the same Node version (at least the major version) in both environments. If the one in your local machine is working, use the `v12.19.0` on both sides. Alternatively, you can use the `v15.0.1` in your local machine, fix the issue, and push the fix.

Use the [NVM (Node Version Manager)](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm) to help you with using Node versions:

```
nvm install 12.19.0
nvm use 12.19.0
```

Comment: still got the same issue. Meanwhile it seems that i can´t even reproduce the site on my local system now. I´ll switch to a earlier version i guess..
But thank you anyway for the help :)

Comment: Remove `node_modules`and `package-lock.json` as well as the cache (or run `gatsby clean`) when switching Node versions

Comment: I stumbled upon this question because I was getting a similar error. Switching to Node 16 and running the first steps of the Gatsby tutorial again fixed it.

Comment: As long as you use the same working version in both environments it should work either way. Of course it's recommended to use the latest LTS Node version if possible. If you change the Node version, you must remove the `node_modules` and the lock file